# Prevent reordering of elements in gestureRecognizers array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I'm experiencing a bug in my app that is causing gestures to stop working that I previously added to a `UITextField` via `addGestureRecognizer:`. Essentially, I add a `tap` and `long press` gesture recognizer to the `UITextField` (which already has 7 gesture recognizers applied from iOS). When logging `self.textField.gestureRecognizers`, it shows the existing 7 gestures and then the two I added at the end of the array. The gestures work just like I expected.

However, when I present a modal view controller and then dismiss it, my two gestures stop working on the text field. I'm not sure exactly why, but the view does disappear and it `resignsFirstResponder` (the keyboard is always up when the modal VC is presented) which may be related. But I discovered the gestures aren't removed from the text field, but the order of the gestures in the array has changed. My custom gestures are now located at index 0 and 1 instead of 7 and 8. I believe the 7 default gestures are conflicting/overriding my custom ones (I assume later placement in the array overrides those before it) which explains why they stop working even though they're still applied.

**My questions are:**
- Do you know why it is reordering the elements in `self.textField.gestureRecognizers`?
- How do I prevent that from occurring to ensure my custom gestures always work, without breaking the default gestures for `UITextField`?

My current solution is to add the two gestures for the first time then store the array of total (9) gestures, then in `viewDidAppear` I change the `gestureRecognizers` array (yes it is settable) to my stored array. This guarantees the array will be the 7 built-in gestures followed by my two custom gestures in that order. But I discovered my gestures are overriding the default gestures (that bring up the popup to Cut, Copy, etc), so I have to reset the gestures back to the default 7 after my custom gesture occurs (which is just fine - I only need to trigger the action a single time after recognizing my custom gesture). Simple enough to do - I store the original gestures in a property as well. But this doesn't feel like the best solution. I'd prefer to figure out the cause and address that or go about the situation differently instead of duct-taping the code together.

Answer (score 0):

> My first solution was to always add my two gestures in viewDidAppear

`viewDidAppear:` is called when your view controller's view first appears, but it is also called again later when the presented view controller is dismissed.

Thus you are adding the gesture recognizers twice.

The simplest solution is to use a BOOL instance variable (we call this a "flag") which you set to YES the *first* time and test afterwards:

```
if (!self.addedGestures) {
    self.addedGestures = YES;
    // ... add them! ...
}
```

Now you will only add them once.

(On the other hand it might be argued that if you care about the order of the gesture recognizers in the array you are already doing something wrong. Use delegate methods to resolve conflicts between gesture recognizers - that's what they are for.)

Comment: The problem isn't ensuring they're only added once. The problem is preserving the order of the gestures in the array, which would not be solved using a simple stored boolean. I do have a working solution but perhaps you could expand on your parenthesized text. That might be something to investigate. Especially because I had to reset the array to its original values after recognizing my gesture. If I can add conditional statements to when a specific gesture should be used that'd be preferred over manually changing the array of gestures. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: How do I use the delegate to determine which gesture should occur - my custom one or ignore all of my custom applied gestures? Example? Do I need to implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` and return NO in the cases where it should not occur and the built-in one should, and that would result in the behavior as if I never applied the gestures? The other methods don't seem to be helpful in this case.

Comment: You want to use `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` and
`gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` as appropriate. _All_ pairs involving your gesture recognizers will be submitted.